# How can I store the resulting MySQL rows into an array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have two functions. They both are very similar in that the one not shown uses a `>` instead of a `<` in the last time check:

```
<?php
function getOldEvents(){
    $con = db::conn();
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE CAST(deleteEvent AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) > ".time()." AND CAST(end AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) < ".time());
    $i = 0;
    $theEvents = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result > 0)) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $theEvents[$i] = $row;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    mysqli_close();
    return $theEvents;
}
?>
```

Regardless of how many times I look at this, I think it should work, but I get an empty array when I check the output with `print_r(getOldEvents())`. I already know the SQL is valid, as I tested in it phpMyAdmin to be sure, and the results are as expected. I am just unable to retrieve the data properly from the `$result` variable. I'll also add that no errors appear on the page or in the log. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can skip the `$i` and just use `$theEvents[] = $row;`

Comment: you can also drop the IF part completely as the while loop is enough to control if there are any rows.

Comment: Ar you sure you are getting results at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result > 0)) {
```

Should be:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

Comment: Strange that this didn't cause any errors. Thanks.